# Angular 5 deleting a post on WP, REST API

Tags: wordpress, angular, rest, api

I'm trying to delete a post using a delete request, but it seems I can't get the headers right.

**project-list.component.ts**

```
deleteProject(project) {
    let headers: Headers = new Headers({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token
    });

    this.projectsService.deleteProject(project.id, { headers: headers }).subscribe(
      result => console.log(result),
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }
```

**projects.service.ts**

```
deleteProject(id: number, { headers: headers }): Observable<Project[]>{
    return this.http.delete<Project[]>(this._wpBase + 'posts/' + id);
  }
```

The DELETE request goes to the right URL, but it's Unauthorized. Under headers it says

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", url: "http://.../wp-json/wp/v2/posts/69", ok: false, …}
```

My guess is it's because of the "headers: HttpHeaders", but I don't know how to fix it. Any help?

Comment: You are not appending the headers to the actual call of `delete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing headers to the delete request. Which you have created in your component.
This is how it should go.

```
deleteProject(id: number, { headers: headers }): Observable<Project[]>{
    return this.http.delete<Project[]>(this._wpBase + 'posts/' + id, headers);
  }
```

**Update:**

Your delete won't return Project object.

```
deleteProject(id: number, { headers: headers }): Observable<any>{
        return this.http.delete(this._wpBase + 'posts/' + id, headers);
      }
```

**Update 2:**

Updated the parameter

```
deleteProject(id: number, headers: any): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.delete(this._wpBase + 'posts/' + id, headers);
}
```

Comment: [ts]
Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<Project[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Project[]>'.
  Type 'HttpEvent<Project[]>' is not assignable to type 'Project[]'.
    Type 'HttpSentEvent' is not assignable to type 'Project[]'.
      Property 'includes' is missing in type 'HttpSentEvent'.


This is what Visual Studio code tells me

Comment: Sadly it's still says unauthorized and the header seems to be empty :c

Comment: Then that could be issue with token you are passing.!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
deleteProject(id: number, headers: any): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.delete(this._wpBase + 'posts/' + id, headers);
}
```